# Find unknown value in probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Suppose that a random variable $Y$ has a p.d.f. given by  $$f (y) = ky^3e^{-y/2}$$ when $y > 0$, and otherwise 0. Find the value of $k$ that makes $f(y)$ a density function.

I found that $k=1.$

> Does $Y$ have a $\chi^2$ distribution? If so, how many degrees of freedom?

$\nu=8$

> What are the mean and standard deviation of $Y$?

Mean is $8$ and standard deviation is $4$.

Could anyone check the answers for me?

Comment: It is a $\chi^2$, $8$ degrees of freedom. I think your $k$ is not correct. Mean and variance are right.

Comment: K=8/3Right......?

Comment: I don't think so, I get $\frac{1}{(16)(3!)}$.

Comment: You are right I make a mistake on 2^4 I thought is 2^(1/4)

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the integral over the p.d.f. via integration by parts. (You don't have to completely repeat this procedure when calculating the mean and variance; writing I(n) for the integral over ky^n*e(-y/2), it's easiest to derive a recurrence relation for I(n) in terms of I(n-1).)

Anyway, I disagree with your value of k - but agree with your mean and standard deviation! I'm surprised the error didn't carry over?